# Regex matching word by exact word length

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to match a word having exact length defined in regex. if word exceed or is bellow the limit it should not match

for example

> Hello match this C90.083635. 11 character long word not C90.083635.73G
>   because it exceed 11 character and not C90.08363 because is not 11
>   character long.

Have tried this `^.{11}$\b^` but it's matching words either 11 chars of word of greater than 11 or less than or the exact

Second problem, Please help with a regex which match a word starting with **specific character** and ends with **.00**  e.g VT500.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the pattern that you tried you are using an anchor `^` which asserts the start of the string and `$` which asserts the end `$`. If you don't want to match spaces you could use `\S` instead of `.`

What you could do instead is match 11 times a non whitespace char and check if it is not surrounded by non whitespace chars.

```
(?<!\S)\S{11}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q3USLk/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/m2bBQ)

For example

```
$re = '~(?<!\S)\S{11}(?!\S)~';
$str = 'Hello match this C90.083635. 11 character long word not C90.083635.73G because it exceed 11 character and not C90.08363 because is not 11 character long.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => C90.083635.
)
```

One option for the second part could be making use of word boundaries `\b` and use `\S+` to  match 1+ times a non whitespace char.

```
\bV\S+\.00\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rxTPGo/1)

Comment: First pattern throw an error: `Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Unknown modifier '\'`

Comment: Second `Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: See this example code https://3v4l.org/LXrYG, and see [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: Thanks, the first one is working the second one still throwing `Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: Thou not an issue it couldn't match vt550.00 but VT550.00, so the option is to uppercase the string.

Comment: Or make the pattern case insensitive https://regex101.com/r/urMI2C/1 using the `i` flag. See https://3v4l.org/k7X4E

Comment: Thanks, that worked. but i would love to learn it so can you break this `~\bV\S+\.00\b~i` down so can understand it and come up with a regex which match "it starts with a digit it has .00 no space it ends with VTS e.g **1,000.00VTS** "

Comment: The `~` are the [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and the `i` makes the patter case insensitive. The pattern itself is `\bV\S+\.00\b`, where `\b` is a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) which is used to prevent the character `B` being part of a larger word. `\S+` repeats 1+ times a non whitespace char and then `\.00` will match a dot literally followed by 2 zeroes and again a word boundary to prevent the last zero being part of a larger word.

Comment: Thanks, so i come up with `~\d\S+VTS~i` to match `it starts with a digit it has .00 no space it ends with VTS e.g 1,000.00VTS` - ofcouse .00 can be `.anyDigit`